# project can't be opened, visual studio crashing

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Last thing I did was add a timer in a user control which updates form color. Now every time I open the project, it loads it up and then says 'Visual Studio Stopped Working'.

I noticed that Visual Studio 'runs' the timer while in designer mode too, so I thought that might be causing the problem so I removed the timer from designer.cs and then renamed all the files Visual Studio was opening, but still it crashes. All the other projects work fine. This is the 4th time that it has happened to me. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Try attaching another Visual Studio to the one that is going to crash (attach BEFORE you open the crashing project). Then maybe you will see where the crash is happening. Clutching at straws maybe, but worth a try.

Comment: Are you using ReSharper?

Comment: @Frank59 I'm not using ReSharper.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, I'm sorry I don't understand how to do that.

Comment: @Kristian You just start up two copies of Visual Studio, and in one of them do "Debug | Attach To Process" and find the OTHER copy of Visual Studio and click "Attach", and then in the OTHER copy of Visual Studio open the project that crashes it.

Comment: Also, if it's completely specific to one solution, try deleting your solution's `*.suo` file.

Comment: I don't know why people are voting to close this as off-topic. It's about an issue with an IDE used to write code, and is perfectly suitable here as a programmer's tool.

Comment: Do you have a prior version you could revert to from your version control system?

Comment: @valverij thanks, that solved the problem!! add your comment as answer and I'll mark it as solution.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

It sounds like your solution settings were corrupted when Studio crashed. You can reset them by deleting your solution's `*.suo` file:

1. Make sure you can [view hidden files](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/show-hidden-files)
2. Find your solution in Windows Explorer. It should be a `*.sln` file
3. There should be a hidden `*.suo` file in the same folder. Delete it.

That will reset all of your solution-specific settings, including the windows you had open.

In the future, you can prevent code from executing in the designer by wrapping it in an `if` using the [`Form.DesignMode` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.designmode.aspx) (inherited from `System.ComponentModel.Component`):

```
if(!this.DesignMode)
{
    /* put code to be excluded from the designer here */
}
```

---

**UPDATE for VS 2017 and 2019**

In VS 2017 and 2019, the `*.suo` file has been moved into a `.vs` folder within the solution directory:

`~/[Solution Directory]/.vs/[Solution Name]/.suo`

You can just delete the entire `.vs` folder to reset your local settings for that solution.

Comment: What if Visual Studio crashes on all projects? even when creating a new one?

Comment: This seems to have fixed it.  I found the suo file in SolutionFolder\.vs\SolutionName\v14 . (Using VS 2015.)  However, I also deleted a StyleCop.cache file.  The problem started for me after doing a Rename.

Comment: In my case was .vs folder. Thanks @valverij

Answer (score 36):

Disabling Visual Studio extensions fixed it for me

Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Installed

In my case, `Web Essentials` was causing the problem

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! Deleting the .suo file resolved nothing in my case, however this answer solved the problem - it looks like another cause for this is when you switch from a web project to an alternative.

Comment: Saved me a MASSIVE headache here mate. Thanks very much for this answer.

Comment: Thank you @branmantwo, I couldn't even open/create a new project until I disabled the package "Web Essentials 2013 for Update 4".

Comment: "Web Essentials" was the victim. Is this a know issue that they will fix sooner?

Comment: This was the answer for me, switching to non-web development made all my projects crash. Removing the SUO file got the projects open again, but the code editor didnt show any text. Disabling web essentials was the solution

Comment: Was experiencing this issue when opening a database project only. VS status bar would show "web essentials applying blah blah blah" then it'd lock my machine up hard! Had to force a power off. Disabling WE was the fix.

Answer (score 12):

If you have a different version of Visual Studio on your computer open that one. Click Debug -> Attach To Process. Select the other Visual Studio process. You should only be able to see one. The Process name is devenv.exe.

Now replicate the problem in the broken VS. It will break on the exception in the unbroken VS.

In my case the exception looked like this

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VSEditor.dll
>
> Additional information: Method 'Connect' in type
>   'JetBrains.UI.SrcView.ContextNotifications.ContextNotificationControl'
>   from assembly 'JetBrains.Platform.UI, Version=104.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1010a0d8d6380325' does not have an
>   implementation.

I fixed it by running the Resharper installer and setting the repair option.

Comment: No need for different versions. I just checked it out with 2 instances of VS2015. Worked well.

Answer (score 4):

Close all the instance of VS 2012.
Open VS 2012 in Admin mode (only VS 2012 no solution), then using this instance of VS try to OPEN the project *.sln.

It should open up properly. For me only this solution works nor deleteing *.suo file neither DISABLING the Extentions and Updates.

Hope this helps. Enjoy.
What is Stopping You :)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure file permissions are consistent.  If the `bin` or `obj` folders can't be accessed, Visual Studio may crash.  Set file ownership and permissions in file properties -> security -> advanced.

Comment: Hey, just an off topic note, all the images in your profile About Me are broken.

Answer (score 2):

Clearing my TFS cache worked for me.

To do so:

1. Close all instances of Visual Studio on the client machine
2. Manually delete the corresponding TFS client cache folder, and then
   start Visual Studio

The corresponding TFS folders to manually delete are as follows:

> TFS 2017: `%localappdata%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\7.0\Cache\`
>
> TFS 2015: `%localappdata%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\6.0\Cache\`
>
> TFS 2013: `%localappdata%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache\`
>
> TFS 2012: `%localappdata%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache\`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a suo file any more in VS 2017.

There is however a hidden `.vs` folder. Try deleting it, worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Let me introduce my case when visual studio was crashing when opening a solution but not any solution, only a solution with DevExpress components, other solutions where opening ok until i tried to add a DevExpress component on the form.

The EventViewer indicated the problem has to do with a DevExpress dll. I repaired the DevExpress installation and the problem is fixed. Something broke my DevExpress installation. This only happened once in 20 years i am using their components and i have no idea what caused the problem in the first place.

Having sent that in most cases that i cannot open a single solution i am deleting the .vs folder or the .suo file and the problem is usually fixed.
Clearing resharper cache may also help sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the Newtonsoft.Json Fixer extension, which worked for me. I had attached another VS to see that the missing file for me was with Newtonsoft.Json, which wasn't referenced by my project, and when I found this extension I thought I'd give it a go.

[image: Newtonsoft.Json Fixer extension]

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't respond to the other comment about extensions, here is **the extension** that was causing this issue for me on Visual Studio 2019 :

`MySQL for Visual Studio`

I recently installed MySQL on my PC and I guess it automatically installs a version for Visual Studio too, I don't know.

Open one of your projects -> in the top bar click on **Extensions** -> Go to **Installed** -> **Disable** MySQL for Visual Studio (or as the other comment suggests, any other extension that might be causing the issue) -> Restart Visual studio