# Visual Studio 2012 Express For Windows 8 has stopped working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-express

Today I downloaded Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8. But whenever I choose to start a new vb windows store project, it shows me that the project is being created and just after it has been created it shows the message that

> Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 For Windows 8 has stopped working. Checking online for solution.

I even read the [Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop has stopped working, VS2010 VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15459654/microsoft-visual-studio-express-2012-for-windows-desktop-has-stopped-working-vs) answers but it didn't help.

I have Visual Studio 2013, Visual Basic 2008 and 6.0 installed. I want to create windows 8 store apps.

Comment: the second answer here, worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364757/project-cant-be-opened-visual-studio-crashing